# Remove product-category from url woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

Problem 1:
I'm using WooCommerce on a WordPress and it adds product-category to the URLs. 
domain.com/product-category/accessories/dishwashing

I need to remove 'product-category' from the URLs. Is there any way to modify the permalinks and remove them? 
Problem 2:
Also, I want to change the permalink for the product.
Current url for product "Active AirClean (SF-AA 50) with TimeStrip" is: 
 http://www.atimiele.co.uk/products/filters/active-airclean-sf-aa-50-with-timestrip/ 
I have a category structure for the product is: 
 accessories > floorcare > filters
So the url for the product shoud be 
http://www.atimiele.co.uk/accessories/floorcare/filters/active-airclean-sf-aa-30-with-timestrip/

Comment: i think this is not possible see here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/

Comment: I found [this](http://www.markwarddesign.com/2014/02/remove-custom-post-type-slug-permalink/) link useful to remove `product` from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are trying to achieve is not possible with Woocommerce. My colleague tried to change this as well a couple of months ago without any success. If you do want to remove the slug from products+categories you can use a plugin. There are several plugins available, i don't know if I im allowed to post it here, but we used the Perfect seo url plugin for woocommerce. www.perfectseourl.com Although it costs a lot of money, it was a good choice.

Typically it will solve both of your questions. I would recommend not using too many 'subcategories' in your url structure. Try to use maximum 2 subcategories, for SEO reasons. Google will index only 3 levels.

Good luck!